# Int to hex string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert an number (integer) to a hex string

```
2 (0x02) to "\x02"
```

or

```
62 (0x0062) to "\x62"
```

How can I do that correctly?

Comment: @Chuck nope that does not cut it^^

Comment: how does that not cut it?

Comment: are you seriously having problems add \x  to the hex number?

Comment: @KeithNicholas No, but I have a problem understanding it, there seems to be a difference between \x2 and \x02. And how can I now that 0x0062 is \x62 as string.

Comment: if you look in the duplicate link shown, there is an implementation of how to padd your hex number with however many 0s you want

Comment: Leading zeroes in hexadecimal don't make any numeric difference. 9 == 09 == 009 == 0009… ad infinitum. I think whatever service you're giving the string to is just a little bit eccentric.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the to string method:

```
a = 64;
a.toString(16); // prints "40" which is the hex value
a.toString(8); // prints "100" which is the octal value
a.toString(2); // prints "1000000" which is the binary value
```

Comment: It has to be in "\x62" format.

Comment: a = 64;
a = '\x' + a.toString(16);

Comment: you can easily concatenate that.

Comment: Doesn't work with 2 as the OP explicitly required the function to return \x02 and not \x2

Comment: @Ibu no you can not... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122373/int-to-hex-string-in-javascript#comment136074488_23122474

Comment: @volter9 This throws a syntax error... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23122373/int-to-hex-string-in-javascript#comment136074488_23122474

Comment: @Mqx you also have to escape the `\` since it is part of the number. so `'\\x' + a.toString(16)`.

Comment: @Ibu but this is just visual... `\\x30` does not represent the actual character `0`.
If you would print `console.log('\\x30');` the output is `\x30`, but if you `console.log('\x30');` you get `0` (which is the actual representation of the HEX code). So `const a = '\x30';` is not the same as `const b = '\\x' + '30';`

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's seems that you want just to concatenate the integer with \x.

If so just to like that:

```
var number = 62;
var hexStr = '\x' + number.toString(16);
```

But you have something strange about explaining.

Note: that 62 is not the same as 0x62, 0x62 would be 98.

Comment: What if number = 2? hexStr would be \x2, but should be \x02

Comment: But what the difference? The value still would be 2. If you need so I'll give you the answer, but there's no difference.

Comment: If I would do this in python I would get "invalid \x escape' while \x02 would be excepted, so there seems to be a difference...

Comment: You're asking about JS, ok never mind. Just add `var hexStr = '\x0' + number.toString(16);`

Answer (score 0):

`var converted = "\x" + number.toString(16)`